# Software KVM For Dual-Displays

Tags: windows, linux, mac, software-rec, kvm-switch

Does a KVM software solution exist that will allow you to utilize two monitors on multiple systems? I'd like to hook up my MBP to my displays, but have the flexibility to switch back to Windows/Linux on a whim.

I have two monitors. I would like the ability to use these monitors from all of my computers using a software-based KVM switch. The alternative is stopping my workflow and manually hooking up the monitors, which is the process I currently use and the process that I'm trying to automate. I'm wondering if such a product exists.

Comment: Okay, deleted my answer since I understand what you mean now.  I'm personally not aware of any product that works in that manner; you might just consider RDP or something like that to accomplish this goal.  (Personally I would buy a hardware KVM...)  It's a good question, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) might meet your needs. :)

Comment: Na, it doesn't. I need video sharing.

Comment: This was in my deleted answer, haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think software is on the wrong side of your KVM problem.

Computers -> video card -> Monitors

If your computers could share a video card, then it could switch what goes out to the monitors, but they don't. So, I see three answers, none of which hit your real question of software KVM.

1) **hardware KVM** - At work, I use the K&M of an IOGear KVM that does fine for me. Just double-tap the scroll lock and you're onto the other source. Problem here is, it only comes with one VGA port, so you'd have to get something like a Matrox TripleHead2Go. I have only heard about the Matrox, so I can't fully back it, and I believe that there's a max-resolution issue with IOGear KVMs that will limit the usefulness. Still, an idea.

2) **Remote Desktop** - Use RDP or VLC to open a connection from one desktop to another. Alternately, you could use PuTTY and XMing to open windows from your Linux box on your Windows box.

3) **Virtualization** - Set up your Windows machine within your Linux machine, or the other way around.

Hope one of these things work.